Next.js 14 failing to build with "Error occurred prerendering page", but builds fine on Vercel
I'm relatively new to Next.js and I'm trying to build my project but I'm encountering an error regarding pre-rendering the pages. I'm using a Provider that pulls configuration settings from the database. It works whenever I'm using the development environment but trying to actually build it gives me an Error occurred prerendering page and TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext'). It also flags all of my pages as having this error so I'm convinced it's the provider that causes this. I'm also using Zustand as my state management.
All of my routes have this error.
ConfigProvider.tsx
"use client";

import { useGlobalStore } from "@/store/useGlobalStore";
import { Config } from "@/types";
import { createContext,  useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";


const ConfigContext = createContext<Config | null>(null)


export const useConfig = () => {
    const context = useContext(ConfigContext)
    console.log("useConfig", context)
    if(context === null) {
        throw new Error("useConfig must be used within a ConfigProvider");
    }
    return context
} 

export const ConfigProvider: React.FC<{children: React.ReactNode}> = ({children}) => {
    const { getConfigQuery } = useGlobalStore();
    const { data, isLoading, error } = getConfigQuery()
    const [config, setConfig] = useState<Config | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data) {
            setConfig(data);
        }
    }, [data]);

    if(isLoading || config === null) return (
        // Loading element
    )

    if (error) {
        console.error("Config loading error:", error);
        return null;
    }
    
    return (
        <ConfigContext.Provider value={config}>
            {children}
        </ConfigContext.Provider>
    )
}

I'm using it to wrap around my <main> element in my layout.tsx.
layout.tsx
export default function RootLayout({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body>
                <Provider>
                    <ConfigProvider>    
                        <main>
                            {children}
                        </main>
                        <Toaster />
                    </ConfigProvider>
                </Provider>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}

The getConfigQuery from useGlobalStore points to a function that accesses my supabase database and returns the data. I'm using Tanstack React Query for this.
export async function transformConfig() {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.from('MySampleTable').select('*')
    if(error){
        console.log(error)
        return {success: false, res: []}
    }
    
    const config = data.reduce((acc: any, item: any) => {
        acc[item.key] = item.value;
        return acc;
      }, {}); 
    
    return config;
}

useGlobalStore.ts
import { transformConfig } from "@/app/ServerAction/config.action";

interface GlobalState {
  getConfigQuery: () => any;
  /* Other states */
}

export const useGlobalStore = create<GlobalState>()((set) => ({

  getConfigQuery: () => {
    return useQuery({
      queryKey: ["GetConfig"],
      queryFn: async () => {
        try {
          const result = await transformConfig();
          return result
        }
        catch (error) {
          console.error("Config query error:", error);
          throw error;
        }
      },
      staleTime: Infinity,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      retry: 1
    })
  },

  /* Other global states */
})




I've tried logging in the ConfigProvider's useEffect, the data starts out as undefined, but it gets populated eventually. If I had to guess, the build error comes from the ConfigProvider needing to load (maybe async?) and initially starts out null/undefined which is why the error is Cannot read properties of null. It also behaves as expected, showing a loading screen during fetching and switching to the actual page once the data loads. It's only during the build that I'm having problems.
Initial null/undefined and data being loaded
What could I do regarding all of these?
PS: My project builds on Vercel without issue. Could it be a problem on my local machine?

where is your transformConfig() function is located ??
which state management are you using ?
could you please share your  GlobalStore code ??

@root_coding Sorry, I was away for a few days. I'm using Zustand for state management. transformConfig() is located in app/ServerAction/config.action.ts. I've also updated the post to include the GlobalStore code.

did you check console the result returned from transformConfig() ? is it okay or undefined ?
the problem is being may be usage of useQuery it should be used outside of zustand store .. inside component so try to update that it may work....

and also you are not setting any value to store so it returns null.
if you are not able to solve then let's catch out on meet and solve this !
